# Spring @RestController single method for anonymous and authorized users

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-restcontroller

I have a following Spring RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1.0/tenants")
public class TenantController {

    @Autowired
    private TenantService tenantService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{tenantId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public TenantResponse findTenantById(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long tenantId) {
        Tenant tenant = tenantService.findTenantById(tenantId);
        return new TenantResponse(tenant);
    }

}
```

`findTenantById` method should be accessed by anonymous and authorized users. In case of anonymous user `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` must return NULL or `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` but in case of authorized - Authentication object.

In my application I have implemented security model with OAuth2 + JWT tokens.

This my config:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http                
            .antMatcher("/v1.0/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/v1.0/tenants/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS); 
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Also, for secure endpoints I'm applying `@PreAuthorize` annotation where needed but not in case of `findTenantById` because as I said previously, I need to grant access to this endpoint for anonymous and authorized users. Inside of endpoint business logic I'll decide who will be able to proceed based on different conditions.

Right now even I have provided my `accessToken` for this endpoint I can't get an authenticated User object from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`.

How to configure this endpoint in order to be working in a way described above ?

Comment: Permit all should permit all users to invoke the controller method. If you ever call `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` in code you are most likely doing something wrong. If you need to know who the user is, you should just include `Authentication auth` in the controller method and Spring will inject it for you, like it does with `Model`, `Session` and a bunch of other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found a solution - I have annotated my method with:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAnonymous() or isFullyAuthenticated()")
```

Please let me know if there is any better solutions.

Comment: Yes, your are right. I have found an issue in my business logic that was a reason of this problem. Now everything works perfectly with `permitAll`. Thanks.